# Visual Studio Debugging Madness!

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am having some really weird stuff happening with my co-workers Visual Studio.

We are totally stumped and I am just throwing this out there in the hopes that someone has a good idea.

Here is the issue:

He has some code that runs on a timer.  In that timer, he does a `lock` to ensure that only one "thread" at a time can get in.

He puts a break point on a spot inside the `lock` and runs to that point.

This is where the weirdness happens.  As he is stepping, the flow will jump him back to that break point after a second or two.  It is very confusing.  The thread ID never changes, so it is not a new thread that is getting past the `lock` somehow.

But here is the really weird part.  It happens every time for him, but when I download the source and try it, it works just fine for me.  I can step through all the code and I never get my next statement "jumping around" (for lack of a better word).

The only difference between his machine and mind is that I have Visual Studio 2010 installed and he does not.  (However, we are both running this in Visual Studio 2008 SP1)

Any ideas?  any at all?  I am really stumped.

Comment: same number of cpu cores etc?

Comment: would you mind to post some code?

Comment: What are you locking on? Can you post the code with the `lock` statement and also show how and where the lock-object is instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is this hotfix:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912

And if I remember right from about 2 years ago, installing the Silverlight SDK also fixed the issue.  I remember thinking that was really strange, but it did the trick for me.  (I actually found that solution before the hotfix)